# Run Snappy Ubuntu Core on Hyper-V in Windows Server 2012

Tags: server, virtualization

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 Server in a Hyper-V VM on Windows Server 2012 and all is working well. I'd like to try Snappy Ubuntu Core in Hyper-V but I've not seen any instructions online explaining how to do it. Can Snappy be run in Hyper-V? If so, can anyone give me any help to get started?